# Is there a .Net wrapper for WinInet

Tags: .net, wininet

I was wondering if there was a .NET wrapper for winInet that gives me managed code. I am aware of .NET wrappers for things like [directx](http://sharpdx.org/) and [openGl](http://www.opentk.com/). For my new job, winInet is very important, however I don't have much knowledge of win32 api or C++.

I took a look over at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718403/c-winhttp-wininet-wrapper-to-post-forms-and-upload-files-without-mfc-atl) and didn't quite see what I was looking for.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983105/windows-api-wrapper-for-net) here is much closer, but the link doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wininet/_ContentBaseDefinition.html

Comment: Any reason your not using the built in HttpWebRequest ?

Comment: Because both of it's constructors are listed as obsolete on the MSDN.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use that syntax (just as a sample):

```
<DllImport("wininet.dll")> _
Public Function InternetGetConnectedState(ByRef description As Integer, Reserved As Integer) As Boolean
End Function
```

So, in your code you just jave to call:

```
If InternetGetConnectedState(0,0) = true
```

Look, it´s just a sample of what you must do.
Good luck